# Lubridate function to convert string into date. Example strings: "21 Apr 2020" or "April 21, 2020"

Tags: r, lubridate

I wanted to know what `lubridate` function can be used to convert these strings to date format.

using `as_date` in the above string is giving warning:

> Warning message:
> All formats failed to parse. No formats found

However, I am able to convert a string like this: "2020 Apr 10 11:22:23" using the `as_datetime` function.

Comment: Does it have to be lubridate? You could use base R `as.Date(x, format = "%d %b %Y")` and `as.Date(x, format = "%B %d, %Y")`.

Comment: class remains character after using this

Answer (score 3):

With `lubridate`, it is just the order of day, month, year that matters.  If we have multiple formats, use `parse_date_time`

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(date1, orders = c('dmy', 'mdy'))
[1] "2020-04-21 UTC" "2020-04-21 UTC"
```

#### data

```
date1 <- c("21 Apr 2020", "April 21, 2020")
```

Answer (score 3):

This is non-`lubridate`, but: if you don't know the order (d-m-y vs m-d-y vs y-m-d) in advance, or if it could be mixed within a single vector, you could try the `anytime` package:

```
anytime::anydate(c("21 Apr 2020","April 21, 2020"))
## [1] "2020-04-21" "2020-04-21"
```

(Apparently `lubridate::parse_date_time()` can handle mixed formats as well: it seems to allow slightly more control of which formats are checked for.)

Answer (score 1):

It was this simple. Thank you guys :)

```
library(lubridate)

a <- "21 Apr 2020"
day1 <- dmy(a)

b <- "April 21, 2020"
day2 <- mdy(b)
```